# Can I make a user control that is a list of user controls?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am created an asp.net web forms page, but I'm coming from MVC world and for reasons beyond my control, I have do use asp.net web forms, which I'm pretty clueless about.  I'm finding it difficult adjusting.  What I'm trying to do may not be possible - I'm trying to create a user control that is a list of user controls.  I'm probably using these things all wrong, but here's what I've got:

**Single control item**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="testUserControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="testUserControl" %>

<tr>
    <td><%= this.NewsId %></td>
    <td><%= this.Title %></td>
    <td><%= this.Body %></td>
    <td><%= this.UserId %></td>
    <td><%= this.DateCreated %></td>
    <td><%= this.ImageId %></td>
</tr>
```

**List control item**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="testListUserControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="testListUserControl" %>
<%@ Reference Control="~/testUserControl.ascx" %>

<table>
    <% foreach (var userControl in TestUserControlItem)
       {
           userControl
       } %>
</table>
```

**List control item code behind**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class testListUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public List<testUserControl> TestUserControlItem { get; set; }
}
```

The list item is where the problem is.  It doesn't work.  Can you see what I'm trying to do?  Is there a better way of doing this or of getting this to work?

Comment: Yes, you can!!!

Comment: Is that you want to wrap all shared user controls to a `UserControl`? Usually inserting `UserControl` in webforms uses `<%# Register Namespace="ControlNamespace" ... %>` then define its tag name & tag prefix, e.g. `<pref:UserControl1 runat="server" ... />`.